# Is it possible to to return nodes with relationships by certain property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

According to Neo4J documentation, I can check to see if a relationship exists between two nodes which return true/false with this code

`MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS (n.name)
RETURN n.name AS name, EXISTS ((n)-[:MARRIED]->()) AS is_married`

I want to know if it's possible to also match by married date (relationship property) to also return true/false.

Example:

`MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS (n.name)
RETURN n.name AS name, EXISTS ((n)-[:MARRIED]->()) WHERE married_date = '2020-03-20' AS is_married`

which will return true or false if if in fact the relationship matches on the date or not.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the property inline in the exists pattern:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS (n.name)
RETURN n.name AS name, EXISTS ((n)-[:MARRIED {married_date:'2020-03-20'}]->()) AS is_married
```

For a more complex filtering (filtering on a range, or pre/suffixes or anything else that can't be captured inline in the pattern itself) we need to look at other options.

Perhaps the best fallback is the usage of [predicate functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/functions/predicate/#query-functions-predicate) over a [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension).

The pattern comprehension provides us the ability to project the relationships into a list, and the `any()` predicate function can check if there are any of those relationships fitting the complex predicate, like so:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS (n.name)
RETURN n.name AS name, any(rel in [(n)-[r:MARRIED]->() | r] WHERE rel.married_date STARTS WITH '2020-03') AS is_married_in_march_2020
```

Comment: You are a life savior. I am not sure why filtering by property type inline like you showed is not mentioned in the documentation. How did you find it?

Comment: The [patterns section of the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-properties) mentions how to specify properties inline. Pattern usage should be pretty much the same whether it's in a MATCH clause, a WHERE clause, a pattern comprehension, or an exists() function.